# Server does not recognize a custom type literal

Tags: postgresql, custom-type

I have created a custom type in postgres:

```
CREATE TYPE semanticversion AS (
    major integer, 
    minor integer, 
    patch integer, 
    prerelease text, 
    prerelease_number integer);
```

And populated some data (`select * from TABLE order by id`):

```
 id |   version   
----+-------------
  1 | (1,0,0,,)
  2 | (2,0,0,,)
  3 | (1,2,3,,)
  4 | (1,2,3,b,1)
  5 | (1,2,3,d,1)
  6 | (1,2,3,h,1)
```

When I order by this field, it works as expected (`select * from TABLE order by version`):

```
 id |   version   
----+-------------
  1 | (1,0,0,,)
  4 | (1,2,3,b,1)
  5 | (1,2,3,d,1)
  6 | (1,2,3,h,1)
  3 | (1,2,3,,)
  2 | (2,0,0,,)
```

But when I try a cutoff (`select * from TABLE where version < (1,2,3,'h',1)`), it throws an error:

```
ERROR:  cannot compare dissimilar column types text and unknown at record column 4
```

I find this confusing, since it is clearly able to compare these values, otherwise it would not be able to successfully order them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type conversion mechanism would need two passes to resolve this case implicitly. Use one of explicit casts:

```sql
where version < (1,2,3,'h'::text,1)
-- or
where version < (1,2,3,'h',1)::semanticversion
-- or
where version < '(1,2,3,h,1)'::semanticversion
```

Comment: That seems to have done it! Now I just need to persuade django to call it like that... Thank you!

Comment: Look here: [Composite types casting.](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#composite-types-casting)

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that - the changes I've made in django are a manual migration to create the type, and subclassing the DatabaseWrapper to map a custom ModelField to the `semanticversion` postgres type.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems doable. One does not exclude the other, though surely it needs some work (I don't use Django).

Comment: Makes sense - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what that `h` in the WHERE clause is supposed to reference, but apart from that it all seems to work for me.

```
richard=> SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY v;
      v      
-------------
 (1,0,0,"",)
 (1,1,0,"",)
 (1,2,0,a,1)
(3 rows)

richard=> SELECT * FROM t WHERE v < (1,1,1,'',null);
      v      
-------------
 (1,0,0,"",)
 (1,1,0,"",)
(2 rows)
```

Comment: The  `h` is part of the ordering, so `(1,2,3,,)` < `(1,2,3,a,1)` < `(1,2,3,b,1)` < `(1,2,3,h,1)` (I'm not especially worried about whether the null (i.e. `(1,2,3,,)`) comes first or last)

Comment: @Alex Do you mean `'h'`?

Comment: @Bergi Apologies, yes, I do